# Angular Material mat-nav-list multiline with centered icon

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I am struggling with trying to setup a mat-nav-list with some -based mat-list-items with two lines. First line should be an image with horizontal center and second line a caption text also centered. Both I got displayed, but the img/icon does not centered. :/

Here is some code:

```
<mat-nav-list class="list-container">
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/somewhere" routerLinkActive="active-link">
      <span matLine class="icn_log"></span>
      <span matLine>Centered Text</span>
    </a> 
</mat-nav-list>
```

I used some styles too, more for getting the paddings off and add some border. But how I can give the first span with the icon the command to get centered too?:

```
.list-container {
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 1px;
   border-right: 1px solid;
   border-color: #ddd;
   text-align: center;
}

.list-container .mat-list-item {
   border: 1px solid;
   border-right: 0px;
   border-color: #ddd;
   margin-top: -1px;
   height: 80px;  
}

.list-container .mat-list-item .mat-line {
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.icn_log {
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-image: url("assets/img/log.png");
   background-position: 0;
}
```

Some code to play: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-94jjyp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT -**

Try changing your background position from `0` to `center` for `icn_log` and `width` to `100%`

```
.icn_log {
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: .icn_og was a typo here, sorry

Comment: @ArgV Do you hav a fiddle/screenshots or something which I can see to find out the issue?

Comment: I added a screenshots

Comment: Still not works :( but I added some code to play :) above

Comment: @ArgV That actually helped. I fixed the issue in the fiddle with the updated changes in the post. I hope it works out the same way for you. Cheers!

Comment: Cool xD Mark it as correct so that the post can be closed @ArgV :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mat-icon` directive like so:

```
<mat-list>
    <a mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon></mat-icon>
        <span matLine>Centered Text</span>
    </a>
</mat-list>
```

Within the `mat-icon` you can use the https://material.io/tools/icons. If you are new to material icons you can follow this guide: https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around for time being but its going to be deprecated, details here

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

```
 :host ::ng-deep .mat-list-item-content {
  flex-direction: column !important;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
<mat-nav-list class="list-container">
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/somewhere" routerLinkActive="active-link">
  <center>
   <span matLine class="icn_log"></span>
   <span matLine>Centered Text</span>
  </center>
</a>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been deprecated from HTML and the author of the post only wants to center the first span.

Comment: what is `matLine`?